# Reading from file into structure, using C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE * fptr;
struct invStruct
{
int frame;
float elec;
float vdw;
float total;
};

int main()
{
int i;
fptr = fopen("/Users/jmindrebo/C_programming/structuretest.txt", "r");
if(fptr == 0){
printf("file not found\n");
exit(1);
}

struct invStruct item[4000] = {0};
for (i=0; i<1; i++)
{
    scanf(fptr, "%d\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%4.f", &item[i].frame, item[i].elec, item[i].vdw, item[i].total);
    printf("%s\t%.4f\t%.4f\t%4.f", item[i].frame, item[i].elec, item[i].vdw, item[i].total);  
}
fclose(fptr);
return 0;
}
```

I am relatively new to coding and I just started learning C last week so this is the best I could come up with so far.  I am trying to read this tab delimited text file into a structure so I can use the values in some calculations. I had trouble loading the values of my text file into a 2D array so I figured this would be easier while still working well enough.

The error that I keep getting is:
/usr/include/stdio.h:274:6: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'struct FILE *'

I have been reading for an hour or two online but I still haven't figured out the issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Line 274 would have been the `scanf` line, so the first thing to do when you see an error about wrong argument types would be to check the documentation for `scanf` (or skip to its declaration in your IDE) and see if your arguments match the expected types.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `fscanf` not `scanf`. Take the habit of reading the documentation of functions you are using, here on [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). If you have the chance of coding on Linux, type

```
man scanf
```

and compile with

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g yourfile.cc -o yourprog
```

then learn how to use the [GDB debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/) (`gdb`) and run

```
gdb yourprog
```

BTW, giving precision in `scanf` format is useless. Using the result of `scanf` or `fscanf` is good practice

```
   int nbread = fscanf(fptr, "%d %f %f %f", 
      &item[i].frame, &item[i].elec, &item[i].vdw, &item[i].total);
   if (nbread != 4) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to read entry #%d (%s)\n", 
              i, strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
```

BTW, you could remove most spaces in `scanf` formats. I usually keep them to 
have the format strings more readable.
You need

```
   #include <string.h>
   #include <errno.h>
```

for `strerror` and `errno` so read [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) and [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

I also suggest to end `printf` format strings with `\n` (since `stdout` is buffered, see [stdout(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html)!) or else use [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) at appropriate places.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` and `fscanf` are different. `scanf`'s first argument is the format string; it outputs to `stdout` by default. The one you want is `fscanf`, which takes the output pointer as its first argument and the format string second. See [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/fscanf.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `fscanf` instead of `scanf`, as others already said. Also add ampersands in front of arguments to scanning function.
You might also remove TAB characters ("\t") from the scanning format.

```
fscanf(fptr, "%d%.4f%.4f%4.f", &item[i].frame, &item[i].elec, &item[i].vdw, &item[i].total);
```